# Sass how to write a base tag and class tags efficiently

Tags: css, sass

Is there an efficient way to write the sass to have a css output like below where I have a native `<p>` tag without a class and then have classes for the `<p>` tag?

**SASS**

```
article {
    .main {
        p {
            margin: 0 auto;
            width: 54.717%;
        }
        p.pull-graph {
                margin-bottom: 1em;
        }
    }
}
```

**CSS**

```
article.main p.pull-graph {
    margin-bottom: 1em;
}
article.main p {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 54.717%;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could avoid to repeat the tagname `p` for every class using the `&` [reference to the parent selector](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#referencing_parent_selectors_)

```
article {
    .main {
        p {
            margin: 0 auto;
            width: 54.717%;

            &.pull-graph {
                margin-bottom: 1em;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As a side note, also consider to mantain your css rules as short as possible (so as to reduce the specificity of your selectors)

E.g. as a small improvement, you could set `role="main"` to the article and use `[role="main"] p` *(specificity 11)* instead of `article.main p` *(spec. 12)*.

Another better improvement could be using HTML5 `<main>` element in place of `article.main` and your selector becomes `main p` *(spec. 2)*